# Playing video from url based on nearest beacon

Tags: xcode, swift, url, video, ibeacon

I am using this project from GitHub for playing 360 video: https://github.com/Aralekk/simple360player_iOS

And I want to play specific video from url based on which beacon is nearest. I added there these properties:

```
var minorOfClosestBeacon = Int()
var playVideo = String()
let urls = [
    40018: "url1",
    38474: "url2",
    60220: "url3"
]
```

And my didRangeBeacons function looks like this:

```
func beaconManager(manager: KTKBeaconManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: KTKBeaconRegion) {
    print("Did ranged \"\(beacons.count)\" beacons inside region: \(region)")
    if beacons.count == 0 {
        userInfoView.hidden = false
    }
    if let closestBeacon = beacons.sort({ $0.0.accuracy < $0.1.accuracy }).first where closestBeacon.accuracy > 0 {
        print("Closest Beacon is M: \(closestBeacon.major), m: \(closestBeacon.minor) ~ \(closestBeacon.accuracy) meters away.")
        minorOfClosestBeacon = closestBeacon.minor.integerValue
        let videoToPlay = self.urls[minorOfClosestBeacon]!
        if playVideo != videoToPlay {
            playVideo = videoToPlay
            play(playVideo)
            print("Playing video: \(playVideo)")
            userInfoView.hidden = true
        } else {
            userInfoView.hidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

When I print there playVideo, it prints me right value, but isn't playing video. When first nearest beacon is the first one in urls array it just isn't playing, but when it is second or third one, then it prints the right value for url, but after that fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.
What should be wrong there?

Comment: The only statement after printing the UTL, is the one that sets `userInfoView.hidden = true`. Where and how is `userInfoView` defined? Try commenting out those lines to see if that solves the fatal error.

Comment: What values do you get for `minorOfClosestBeacon`? Try removing the if conditional `if playVideo != videoToPlay` to see if that plays the first video.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.` is caused by the bang in this line:

```
let videoToPlay = self.urls[minorOfClosestBeacon]!
```

I would replace that with:

```
if let videoToPlay = self.urls[minorOfClosestBeacon] {
  // Put the rest of your code here
  ...
}
else {
  print "No video found for minor \(minorOfClosestBeacon)"
}
```

It's hard to say why the video wouldn't be playing without seeing the contents of the `play` method.  Perhaps you need to run it on the main thread with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
  play(playVideo)
}
```

I would verify that `play` method call works by itself with a hard-coded url before getting it to work with all the beacon logic.

Comment: It is printing me now No video to play for minor... So it gives me that else

Comment: Ok, what minor number does it print with the else?  Do you have a video configured for that number?

Comment: Okay, now it prints me the right playVideo, but when the first beacon is the nearest it will just play nothing. But if second or third is the nearest, then when I tap play button, it gives me fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.